# Ensure only one of the several records for a given item has a column with true value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called `Computer` with columns:

```
id
NIC_name
is_primary
```

My primary key is `(id, NIC_name)` and `is_primary` is a `bit` field for a boolean value.

I would like to ensure that for all computers with same `id` there is always zero or one records whose `is_primary` is set to true. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: `group by` and `count()` might do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a filtered index to enforce uniqueness on id and is_primary when is_primary is 1.

An example here:

```
create table Computer(
    id char(20) not null
  , NIC_name varchar(100) not null
  , is_primary bit not null
  , constraint pk_computer primary key (
    id asc,
    NIC_name asc
    )
);

create unique index ix_one_primary on Computer(id, is_primary) where (is_primary=1);

-- these three are fine
insert Computer(id, NIC_name, is_primary)
values('computer1','foo',0);

insert Computer(id, NIC_name, is_primary)
values('computer1','bar',1);

insert Computer(id, NIC_name, is_primary)
values('computer1','foobar',0);

-- this one is not allowed
insert Computer(id, NIC_name, is_primary)
values('computer1','oops',1);
```

Comment: Thank you, you did answer my question. Taking your idea I did this using SQL Serve Management Studio. I'll post what I did in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from [@Mister Magoo](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/108264/45857) is great. I used SQL Server Management Studio to do the same task. I followed the instructions [here from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372(v=sql.110).aspx#SSMSProcedure). Pasting below as well for convenience:
To create a filtered index

1. In Object Explorer, click the plus sign to expand the database that contains the table on which you want to create a filtered index.
2. Click the plus sign to expand the Tables folder.
3. Click the plus sign to expand the table on which you want to create
   a filtered index.
4. Right-click the Indexes folder, point to New Index, and select
   Non-Clustered Index….
5. In the New Index dialog box, on the General page, enter the name of
   the new index in the Index name box.
6. Under Index key columns, click Add….
7. In the Select Columns from table_name dialog box, select the check
   box or check boxes of the table column or columns to be added to the
   unique index. I selected`id` and `is_primary`.
8. Click OK.
9. On the Filter page, under Filter Expression, enter SQL expression
   that you’ll use to create the filtered index. I used: `is_primary=1`
10. Click OK.

Comment: You know you could just run - through SSMS since you prefer it - the statement provided by @MisterMagoo: `create unique index ix_one_primary on Computer(id, is_primary) where (is_primary=1);`